# android.permission.INTERNET is a Security Risk?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, android-security

I have developed a flutter app for Android and iOS. It is an online ordering app, but you can't make payments. It was sent to a security audit by the customer. In the Audit, they said `android.permission.INTERNET` is enabled and its a security risk. But this sounds nonsense to me, because this app need to work with internet

They provided the following technical background

> To maintain security for the system and users, Android requires apps
> to request permission before the apps can use certain system data and
> features. Depending on how sensitive the area is, the system may grant
> the permission automatically, or it may ask the user to approve the
> request. As mentioned in the table above certain parameters may be
> used to collect data which may lead to privacy concerns.

Then recommended the below

> It is recommended to consider each feature provided by the respective
> parameter and assess the business requirement in enabling the same.

Well, I dont know what to do about this. No internet means you can't order anything in this online ordering app.

Below is my Android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.appname">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="MY APP"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is my pubspecs.yaml file

```
name: MyApp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.2+3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: ^0.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^4.0.4
  badges: ^1.1.1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
  intl: ^0.16.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  
  build_runner: ^1.7.4
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.jpg"


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/lock_24px.png
    - assets/images/email_24px.png
    - assets/images/shopping_cart_48px.png
    - assets/images/logo_2.jpg
    - assets/images/fish1.png
    - assets/images/fish2.png
    - assets/icons/account-filled.png
    - assets/icons/account-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/history-filled.png
    - assets/icons/history-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/home-filled.png
    - assets/icons/home-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/notifications-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/notifications-filled.png
    - assets/images/loading_image2.gif

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
    - family: Ma Shan Zheng
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MaShanZheng-Regular.ttf
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Whats going on here? What is the step I should take on this?

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it but convincing them, explaining why it's needed and why you can't remove that, and referencing google's documentation about android permission and what is `android.permission.INTERNET`. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting , https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INTERNET

Comment: @Amir_P: Yes, to me this seems like they handed over some general suggestions as well, so this internet thing came up

Answer (score 0):

The `Internet` permission has a normal protection level and must not be granted at runtime.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INTERNET

> Normal permissions
>
> Normal permissions cover areas where your app needs to access data or resources outside the app's sandbox, but where there's very little risk to the user's privacy or the operation of other apps. For example, permission to set the time zone is a normal permission.
>
> If an app declares in its manifest that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time. The system doesn't prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal_permissions

The remark from the security audit doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Comment: `The Internet permission has a normal protection level and must not be granted at runtime.` - what does this mean? then to enable internet, what should i do? Also in `Flutter`, the official document itself recommend to add this at release - https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest

Comment: You don't need to do anything besides adding the permission to the manifest. I don't see a problem in doing so.